# Testing procedure

Tags: testing, project-management, installation, project

I developed one application, and starting the testing phase soon,

While I'm trying to setup a testing plan, I have one question!

Shall I start by testing the actual application functionality, or the installation procedure first? (Please note that the installer is an actual project we have)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully the functionnalities of the application itself and the installer are unrelated, and you can test them in any order.

**Edit: Answer to comment**
Let me reformulate : hopefully the two assumptions :

*1) My installer will put my user system in the proper state for my application to run*

and

*2) Provided the system is in the proper state, my application runs properly*

are unrelated. Obviously, if your installer fails, your application won't work if installed by the installer :)

If you have doubts about that (and in particular are unsure about the definition of "proper state") that's probably the first thing you should test : what kind of "state" do you need for your application to run. Then you can test the installer and the application independantly

Comment: The application functionality and the Installation procedure are related, DB Script, initiate some parameters, setting Services, ini files, IIS websites and virtual directory.

Comment: My answer doesn't fit in comments, so I updated the answer.

Comment: +1: "Install manually and test" is completely unrelated to "Run installer and confirm it was installed".  One set of tests confirms it works; the other confirms it got installed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter?

Having an installer might make the testing of the application easier (for QA) in that you don't have to do any manual steps as a tester if there is an installer program.

If it were me I would just have the installer testing be a subset of the product testing.  (This is for QA testing, not unit testing)

Answer (score 0):

You should to test what will hurt you most should you find faults, that way if you find a really big problem at least you'll know as soon as possible and can manage expectations accordingly.

In your case I imagine that the application poses the greatest risk and should focus on this initially.